# Где хранится код снипетов в modx?

Tags: modx

Я пишу свой снипет. Пишу его в админке modx. У меня вопрос: а физически этот файл где то сохраняется? Что бы открыть его через редактор и там писать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В БД. ЕМНИП - таблица modx_snippets.

И есть были плагины для выноса в файлы (вероятно - подойдёт https://modx.com/extras/package/staticsaver ?)

Answer (score 1):

В редактировании сниппета, поставьте галочку "статичный" и можете писать свой сниппет в отдельном файле, в нормальном редакторе по фтп и даже не заходить в админку modx